# how to place multiple set of equations inside one trigger

Tags: mysql, database

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `ia_att` decimal(3,2) NULL,
      `t1` decimal(3,2) NULL,
      `t2` decimal(3,2) NULL,
      `t3` decimal(3,2) NULL,
      `ia_tot` decimal(3,2) NULL,
      .....
      .....
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    );      

 CREATE TRIGGER tg_bi_test
    BEFORE INSERT ON test
    FOR EACH ROW 
      SET NEW.s1_ia_tot = 
         (NEW.s1_t1 + NEW.s1_t2 + NEW.s1_t3 -
          LEAST(NEW.s1_t1, NEW.s1_t2, NEW.s1_t3)) / 2 + 
         CASE 
           WHEN NEW.s1_ia_att > 95 THEN 5
           WHEN NEW.s1_ia_att BETWEEN 81 AND 95 THEN 4
           WHEN NEW.s1_ia_att BETWEEN 76 AND 80 THEN 3
           WHEN NEW.s1_ia_att BETWEEN 61 AND 75 THEN 2
           WHEN NEW.s1_ia_att < 60 THEN 0 

      SET NEW.s2_ia_tot = 
         (NEW.s2_t1 + NEW.s2_t2 + NEW.s2_t3 -
          LEAST(NEW.s2_t1, NEW.s2_t2, NEW.s2_t3)) / 2 + 
         CASE 
           WHEN NEW.s2_ia_att > 95 THEN 5
           WHEN NEW.s2_ia_att BETWEEN 81 AND 95 THEN 4
           WHEN NEW.s2_ia_att BETWEEN 76 AND 80 THEN 3
           WHEN NEW.s2_ia_att BETWEEN 61 AND 75 THEN 2
           WHEN NEW.s2_ia_att < 60 THEN 0
           --------
           --------
         END;
```

What is wrong in creating trigger like this?? i want to creat this for seven coloums that is ia_tot in one table please help me is this possible in mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little hint - create an user definied function that does all calculations:

```
delimiter $$
create function my_calculation( ia_att decimal, t1 decimal, t2 decimal, t3 decimal )
returns int
deterministic 
begin 
  RETURN
  (t1 + t2 + t3 - LEAST(t1, t2, t3)) / 2
  +
  CASE 
    WHEN ia_att > 95 THEN 5
    WHEN ia_att BETWEEN 81 AND 95 THEN 4
    WHEN ia_att BETWEEN 76 AND 80 THEN 3
    WHEN ia_att BETWEEN 61 AND 75 THEN 2
    WHEN ia_att < 60 THEN 0 
   END;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

and use this function in your trigger:

```
delimiter $$
create trigger abc before insert 
on `test` for each row
begin
   declare `value` decimal;

   SET NEW.s1_ia_tot = my_calculation( NEW.s1_ia_att, NEW.s1_t1, NEW.s1_t2, NEW.s1_t3 );
   SET NEW.s2_ia_tot = my_calculation( NEW.s2_ia_att, NEW.s2_t1, NEW.s2_t2, NEW.s2_t3 );
   SET NEW.s3_ia_tot = my_calculation( NEW.s3_ia_att, NEW.s3_t1, NEW.s3_t2, NEW.s3_t3 );
   ......
end $$
delimiter ;
```

This will make your code shorter, more clear and easier to maintain.

Another remark - DECIMAL(3,2) stores numbers with maximum 3 digits, and 2 digits to the right of the decimal point. That measn, that there is only ONE digit ( 3 - 2 = 1 ) to the left of the decimall point, and can store numbers only up to 9.99, not more. If the number will be 10 or more, you will get an error. 

**---- EDIT -----**
Here is a link to a working demo --> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93c8d/4

Comment: when i run this in mysql workbech the cmd select my_calculation( s2_ia_att, s2_t1, s2_t2, s2_t3 )
from test; shows the result but the result is not getting updated in the s2_ia_tot or any of the result columns

Comment: the above works like a charm but doesnt update in my table only in view it works. trigger is not working for me.

Comment: insted of befor insert i got result form using before update command